# Ensuring an Event listener is called after extending an Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, extend, super

If I extend Activity and implement an event handler in my base class (sorry if that's not the correct OOP term) how can I ensure that my event handler always gets run from classes which extend mine.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//Stuff that I need to do.
}

}//MyActivity class

public class MainActivity extends MyActivity{


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}//MainActivity class
```

The intention is that MyActivity is going to end up in a code library that other users will be using.
Both my class and the instances of Activity which extend my class have separate valid uses for  `onActivityResult`.  I obviously can't make `onActivityResult`  final to stop people from overriding it.

Now if the users forget to add that super statement, my code isn't run. Is there any way to force instances of classes extending MyActivity to run super in methods that overlap on methods defined by me in the parent class.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217013/how-to-force-derived-class-to-call-super-method-like-android-does

Answer (score 2):

If a later programmer chooses not to call `super` then that is their decision and they will lose the benefit of inheriting from your class.  So far as I know, there is no way to guarentee `super` will be called or any way to force them to call it.

Comment: ok, but say if your base activity opens some resources, and you extend that activity and make your base activity available to other in a library. You then have no definite way of ensuring that your resource clean up code is executed.

Comment: Good point. I guess my best advice is: maybe your base activity shouldn't be opening resources it can't close.  I'm not a Design Patterns expert, but that's the best I can offer.  You could try leaving a `protected` getter to the resource so that overriding classes have access to it, then leave explicit documentation that future classes must take care of it (or at least call super).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't force the super method to be called.

However, you can develop MyActivity in such a way to make it easier to understand how the developer should use it.

If your parent class, MyActivity, is never going to be instantiated you can make it an abstract class.

Abstract classes can contain methods that can call to abstract methods.

Abstract methods **must** be implemented in the class that extends it.

So you could write something like

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity{

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   //Stuff that I need to do.
   onMyActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public abstract void onMyActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);

}//MyActivity class

public class MainActivity extends MyActivity{

@Override
public void onMyActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}

}//MainActivity class
```

Comment: I'm not sure you get what I'm trying to do. I want to ensure that my code in the base class gets call but if the onActivityResult in MainActivity does not have a super.onActivityResult statement, then the event handler in the base class does not get called.

Comment: As far as I know, the other answer is correct, there is no way to do that. Instead, the answer I gave is an alternative solution - you give them a different method that they MUST implement. You can't stop them from overriding onActivityResult, but if you give them another method that they must implement that allows them to do what onActivityResult is for, then at least other developers will be able to do what they need and will be forced to understand why onMyActivityResult exists.